# Store response from Volley in shared preference

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am a newbie to android. I am trying to use Volley for posting my form data to server.I am able to successfully post the data, and I am getting respons like this

> {"status":"success","username":"User Vishnu","userid":"124","role":"UU"}

I need to store the values of this response to sharedpreference. How can I achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.
I have the following code written in my activity

```
 JsonObjectRequest stringRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, loginURL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    JSONObject josnOBJ = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jArray = josnOBJ.getJSONArray();
                    JSONObject jsonData = null;
                    String title = null;

                    for (int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            jsonData  = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            title= jsonData  .optString("role");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // Oops
                        }
                    }
                    String bla= response.toString();
                    Log.i("Responses",bla);
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,bla,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DrawerSelectorActvity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).
```

PS: There are errors in the code.This is the code I have tried so far.

Comment: Well what is the problem? I see no code with shared preferences. You want to write some strings to shared preferences?

Comment: If the response has multiple title value (JSONArray length is more than 1) then all titles will be replaced by the last one.

Comment: I know how to add values to shared preferences..But how can get the values from the above response so that I can store in sharedpref

Comment: What has that to do with shared preferences? I still see no code. And it is unclear which strings you want to save.

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury JSONArray lenght will alwaya be 1 in this response

Comment: You want to parse out the values for the four items in that json text?

Comment: @greenapps yes exactly..How can I get the username/role from the JSONArray in volley response

Comment: Then edit your post. Remove all the code. Remove all volley and shared preferences talk. Just ask how to get the values for the items from that text. Show only some code where you try yourself. This is about json parsing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108071/discussion-between-amit-nair-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Add code in volley onResponse.

```
JSONObject josnOBJ = new JSONObject(response);

            String username= jsonOBJ.getString("username");
            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            editor.putString("username", username);
            editor.commit(); // or editor.apply();
```

Comment: This will save the entire response..right?Suppose I need to store only username from the response..what should I do

Comment: yes, then you need to get json value using key (username). Check updated answer. i hope it work.

Comment: And imp : This is your final json response or only sample? If final then your response is JSONObject not JSONArray. so you can simply get value using response.getString("username")

Comment: this is my final json response